# Program to encrypt folders that works in Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, linux, encryption

I'm using a crypt solution called DriveCrypt(for windows). But now I need a solution that does the same that DriveCrypt does but must to work in both Windows and Linux.

Somebody know some software that works in Linux and Windows to encrypt folders?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) claims to be open-source and work on Windows, Linux, and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

In order to archive a directory into an encrypted package.

Combine tar, gzip and gpg. You will need the GnuWin32 utils installed, as well as GnuPG.

```
tar czf archive.tar.gz mydirectory/  # => archive.tar.gz 
gpg -c archive.tar.gz                # Input password. => archive.tar.gz.gpg
rm -rf mydirectory archive.tar.gz    # remove the plaintext residue.
```

gpg -c is symmetric encryption.